Raspberry PI 3B GPIO not working using Node or terminal
I have created a simple circuit with the aim to make a red LED blink. I have connected the circuit correctly to PIN 16.
I have written code in python and the light blinks
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
import time 
LED_PIN = 16

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

try 
   GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
   Time.sleep(5)
   GPIO.output(LED_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   Pass
finally:
GPIO.cleanup

However, when I try to execute the export command from the terminal, I get an error.
echo 16 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export 

The error is:
[Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, write] {
  errno: -22,
  code: ‘EINVAL’,
  syscall: ‘write’  
}

I get the exact same error while running node js

const gpio = require(‘rpi-gpio’).promise;
async function main() {

  const pin = 16;
  await gpio.setup(pin, gpio.OUT);
  Gpio.write(pin, true); 
}

main();

>> node ./index.js

Node:internal/process.promises:279
    TriggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise*/);

[Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, write] {
  errno: -22,
  code: ‘EINVAL’,
  syscall: ‘write’  
}

I wanted to use javascript as I am teaching it to my kids. However, I am not sure why the terminal and node are throwing bad argument errors while python3 works!
I am running PI board version 3B with latest Raspberry Pi OS release 5.2 March 2024.
I have tried node versions 16, 18 and 20.

with latest release OS release 5.2 huh? What OS is that? Is that the kernel version? The whole sysfs interface is being deprecated - check the issues for rpi-gpio library - note, as per one issue, adding 512 to the GPIO number usually works (so, 528 instead of 16)

Adding 512 did not work. The OS is raspberry PI OS. I have updated the description.

The OS is raspberry PI OS which release? 32/64bit?

The library is too old. I have checked the source code of both libraries. Ended up answering my own question :-(

The /sys/class/gpio has been deprecated. The gpio commands don’t work like expected in the latest Raspberry OS (bookworm).
I have looked into the code of the onoff library and it uses the old API “/etc/class/gpio”. The first handful of lines show this:
https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/blob/master/onoff.js

'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const debounce = require('lodash.debounce');
const Epoll = require('epoll').Epoll;

const GPIO_ROOT_PATH = '/sys/class/gpio/';

const HIGH_BUF = Buffer.from('1');
const LOW_BUF = Buffer.from('0');

const HIGH = 1;
const LOW = 0;

The library has not been updated since more than 3 year. Other JS libraries suffer the same maintenance issue.
The python library RPi.GPIO is written in C underneath and uses the recommended API gpiomem like shown here below:
https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/c_gpio.c
int setup(void)
{
    int mem_fd;
    uint8_t *gpio_mem;
    uint32_t peri_base = 0;
    uint32_t gpio_base;
    uint8_t ranges[12] = { 0 };
    uint8_t rev[4] = { 0 };
    uint32_t cpu = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    char hardware[1024];
    int found = 0;

    // try /dev/gpiomem first - this does not require root privs
    if ((mem_fd = open("/dev/gpiomem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC)) > 0)
    {
        if ((gpio_map = (uint32_t *)mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
            return SETUP_MMAP_FAIL;
        } else {
            return SETUP_OK;
        }
    }

    // revert to /dev/mem method - requires root privileges

    if ((fp = fopen("/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges", "rb")) != NULL)
    {

Here is the old way and the new way to communicate with the pins from the terminal:
Old way
echo 16 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/direction
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/gpio16/value
echo 16 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/unexport

New way
pinctrl set 16 op dh. # set as high
pinctrl set 16 op dl. # set as low


Or, if you want to use the command line, you could use the gpiod tools.  With the v1 tools currently packaged in Raspberry Pi OS the commands would be gpioset 0 16=1 and gpioset 0 16=0.  Those use the /dev/gpiochip interface which is more portable than the /dev/gpiomem interface which is Raspberry Pi specific and changed drastically for the Pi5.

/dev/gpiomem is very wrong approach.
